# Count all row based on id from a different table

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I want to count the `photo` based on `product id`. I think there is something to do in loop counting. So I coded as following but I got

**Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object**

```
<?
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/cgi-bin/connect.php");

$stmt=$mysqli->prepare("select * from products_db order by prd_id");
$stmt->execute();
$result=$stmt->get_result();
$data=array();
while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
    //count no. of img in loop
    $stmt=$mysqli->prepare("select pic_id from photo_db where pic_sid=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$row['prd_sid']);
    $result=$stmt->get_result();
    $nPic=$result->num_rows;

    $data[]=array($row['prd_code'],$row['prd_en'],$row['cat_id'],
number_format($row['prd_cost']),$row['prd_stts'],$nPic,$row['prd_rcm']);
}
echo json_encode(array('data' => $data));
?>
```

Then I do :

```
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare("select *,count(pic.pic_id) as npic 
from products_db prd 
inner join 
photo_db pic 
on prd.prd_sid=pic.pic_sid 
order by prd.prd_id");
```

It's working **BUT SOME PRODUCTS WAS UNSHOWN BECAUSE NO RELATED `pic_sid` FROM `photo_db`**

I want all product display the photo count even there's none of them existed in DB.

Comment: You need to use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`

Comment: I would recommend that you try not to use `*` in selects unless you need to and your last SQL should have a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: you can count rows from this query $stmt=$mysqli->prepare("select * from products_db order by prd_id"); why do you need join

Comment: @Nick I tried but I still cannot count the photo where's no `prd_sid` presented.

Comment: @NigelRen It's doesn't make any change to the production.

Comment: @Zeljka So what's the different to my code?

Comment: hmm sorry you can do something like this

Comment: dont use count, you  can use   sum(if(pic.pic_id is null or pic.pic_id is not null, 1, 0)) asnpic or you can sum those without pic or with picture like this sum(if(pic.pic_id is null, 1, 0)) wuthout pic, sum(if(pic.pic_id is not null, 1, 0)) with pic and use left join

Comment: @NigelRen ok, any related guide to the solution please?

Comment: select count(pi.pic_id),pr.* from photo_db pi where pi.pic_sid in (select  pr.prd_sid from products_db pr ) group by pi.pic_id

Answer (score 0):

Try this query I hope it will work.

```
select count(pi.pic_id),pr.* from photo_db pi where pi.pic_sid in (select pr.prd_sid from products_db pr ) group by pi.pic_id
```

Comment: Yeah, pretty much close to the reality. But the query return all null. Suggestion?

Comment: can you make a demo of your database on SQLfiddle and run this query there so that I can see what you are getting and what you are not getting. 

http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: or update table demo in your question and the output you are expecting.

Comment: Something like this is working but it ignore the row of photo_db as it doesn't existed. 

`SELECT *,count(pic.pic_id) as npic FROM photo_db pic left join products_db prd on prd.prd_sid=pic.pic_sid group by pic.pic_sid`

Comment: you want all the columns of photo_db?

Comment: How can I understand the logical error you are getting from query which is wrong. to solve it i need demo of database table and the expected result demo.

Comment: based on your code. I changed some variables and it's now working. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Wilf ok then please accept the answer and close this thread :) or vote up if it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Thank to the advice from `@Sayed Mohd Ali`. I come up with the solutions.

```
select *,
(select count(pic_id) as npic from photo_db where pic.pic_sid=prd.prd_sid) as npic
from products_db prd
left join photo_db pic on pic.pic_sid=prd.prd_sid
group by prd.prd_sid
```